# Emails not received in Opencart-3 from the same adress (from admin to admin email)

Tags: email, routes, opencart, opencart-3

Please Help ...

I debug it and everything looks fine, I configured the SMTP in admin successfully and emails working fine but in case, If we add the same Hosting Domain name, while sending email then It's not working ???

Example: Forgot password not working because URL there but In admin "Marketing => Mail" working, If I do not add domain name. (NOTE: Other domain name working, If I add only opencart3 hosted domain name not working in email)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like not an OpenCart issue, but a hosting configuration. As you said, when you are using same domain name in email, as a site domain - sometimes it's a routing incorrect.

Check an email configuration on your server. When you trying to sent an email to same-domain address - it could be routed as an inner massage. For example, in **cPanel** hosting settings you should inspect "Mail forwarding" and can check the status of messages in "Track delivery".

If you are using cPanel - go to Mail forwarding, find you domain, and change settins:

- Automatically Detect Configuration. - *will be set by default.*
- Local Mail Exchanger. - *try this.*
- Backup Mail Exchanger.
- Remote Mail Exchanger. - *or this.*

Or you can ask you hosting support. Your question will be *"I'm trying to use an email address mayaddress@mydomain.com via SMTP on my mydomain.com, but when i try to sent an email to the same address - the message is missing. Can you check email routing settings?"*

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply... yes you are right. It's a server configuration issue. I bought the Gmail SMTP plugin and now I am sending email using this plugin and It's working fine for me. I will contact same to hosting provider as well. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to read that! Although, you can mark the answer as a correct got the community to know your problem is solved.